# Convert an complicated excel sheet data into csv file using Unix

Tags: csv, unix, export-to-csv

I need to convert data of two sheets from one excel into csv files. Data section starts from 8th row and 2nd column in sheet. Column header is on 7th row then data. How can this be done in Unix shell scripting.

https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/methods-convert-xlsx-format-files-csv-linux-cli/

I read couple of article but none giving idea to start the read/convert of sheet from certain column and row

Excel data of sheet is as:

```
    This is the information of employee in company FRDN
```

This is data of year 2019

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME  EMAIL   PHONE_NUMBER    HIRE_DATE   JOB_ID  SALARY  COMMISSION_PCT  MANAGER_ID  DEPARTMENT_ID   LAST_NAME
100 Steven  SKING   515.123.4567    6/17/1987   AD_PRES 24000           90  King
101 Neena   NKOCHHAR    515.123.4568    9/21/1989   AD_VP   17000       100 90  Kochhar
102 Lex LDEHAAN 515.123.4569    1/13/1993   AD_VP   17000       100 90  De Haan
103 Alexander   AHUNOLD 590.423.4567    1/3/1990    IT_PROG 9000        102 60  Hunold
104 Bruce   BERNST  590.423.4568    5/21/1991   IT_PROG 6000        103 60  Ernst
```

csv file is needed for the sheet of excel and data start from a certain row and column.

Answer (score 0):

This command will help you to convert your Excel file into CSV.

libreoffice -display :0  --headless --convert-to csv --outdir "/path/" "/path/FileName.xls"